# phantomjs failed to load dynamic page

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I use Python selenium with phantomjs driver to scrape landing pages of website.

One site Phantomjs failed is : http://stance.com . It looks like the site uses angularjs and expressjs

My code is simply:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PHANTOMJS()
driver.get(http://www.stance.com')
```

The response is basically empty. Can anyone provide hints on why it failed? and what I can do to make to work.

Comment: did you tried `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` or `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`?

Comment: @dev_strender no, my code runs on a virtual machine, which doesn't have display. I know there're ways to set up firefox, but I would prefer phantomjs